# How to query Laravel Eloquent belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I am studying the Laravel Eloquent Relationships, with different examples. I have a  State model and City model, where City ***belongsTo*** State and State ***hasMany*** City.

As per given code on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading, I successfully queried the states which have cities whose name starts with 'p'. But I am unable to retrieve all those cities whose state names start with 'l'.

This could be a very basic question, but still, I am seeking for help for what goes unsuccessful and why.

Comment: Thanks @afraz. Isn't is possible to query through the State model, like $states= States::where('city', function ($query) {
   $query->where('name', 'like', 'p%');
})->get(); ?

Comment: Above will return you states where related cities name starts with letter p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
State::where('name','like','l%')->get();
```

**For querying relationship:**

```
$states= City::whereHas('state', function ($query) {
   $query->where('name', 'like', 'l%');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `whereHas` to apply filter on related models like

```
$states= City::whereHas('state', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', 'i%');
})->get();
```

[Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)